# Need count value in same tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have below tables, Here, I want to get the count of the value STAT_NEW = 'Sent to xxxx Project Team'. We need the count values before occuring the values stat_new='Sent to VMO'.

```
SQL> Select * from sample_test;


ID  CONTRACT_ID                STAT_NEW                                 UPD_DT  
-----------------------------  -------------------------------------- ----------
0   CR 01 to MWO 1            Sent to xxxx Project Team               11-AUG-13
1   CR 01 to MWO 1            Sent to xxxx Project Team               11-AUG-13 
2   CR 01 to MWO 1            Sent to xxxx Project Team               11-AUG-13
3   CR 01 to MWO 1            Sent to VMO                             12-AUG-13 
4   CR 01 to MWO 1            Sent to xxxx Project Team               11-AUG-13 
5   CR 01 to MWO 1            Sent to xxxx Project Team               11-AUG-13
6   CR 01 to MWO 1            Sent to VMO                             12-AUG-13

7   CR 01 to MWO 2            Sent to xxxx Project Team               11-AUG-13 
8   CR 01 to MWO 2            Sent to xxxx Project Team               11-AUG-13 
9   CR 01 to MWO 2            Sent to xxxx Project Team               11-AUG-13 
10  CR 01 to MWO 2            Sent to VMO                             12-AUG-13
11  CR 01 to MWO 3            Sent to xxxx Project Team               12-AUG-13 
12  CR 01 to MWO 3            Sent to xxxx Project Team               12-AUG-13
13  CR 01 to MWO 3            Sent to VMO                             13-AUG-13

7 rows selected
```

I have tried below scenario whihc is giving particular contract id and if having only one Sent to VMO then the below scenario is working.

```
select count(*) from sample_test where upd_dt <= (select UPD_DT from sample_test where stat_new='Sent to VMO' and contract_id='CR 01 to MWO 1') AND stat_new='Sent to xxxx Project Team';
```

My expected output is like below....

```
CONTRACT_ID      count of STAT_NEW='Sent to xxxx Project Team'
--------------   ------------
CR 01 to MWO 1    3
CR 01 to MWO 1    2
CR 01 to MWO 2    3
CR 01 to MWO 3    2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT CONTRACT_ID,COUNT(STAT_NEW) STAT_NEW_COUNT FROM
(
    SELECT t.*
        ,(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM #MyTable WHERE STAT_NEW='Sent to VMO' AND ID < t.ID) AS cnt
    from #MyTable t
    WHERE STAT_NEW<>'Sent to VMO'
) tt
GROUP BY CONTRACT_ID,cnt
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/mkJtrg)

**OUTPUT**

```
CONTRACT_ID      STAT_NEW_COUNT
CR 01 to MWO 1     3
CR 01 to MWO 1     2
CR 01 to MWO 2     3
CR 01 to MWO 3     2
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit trickier than it seems.  The following should work:

```
select contract_id, sum(case when stat = 'Sent to xxxx Project Team' then 1 else 0 end) 
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when stat = 'Sent to VMO' then 1 else 0 end) over
                 (partition by Contract_Id order by id desc) as SentVMOcount
      from sample_test t
     ) t
where sentVMOcount = 1
group by contract_id;
```

The key here is `sentVMOcount`.  This uses the cumulative sum analytic function to enumerate the rows based on the `'Sent to VMO'` status that occurs after that row.  So, all the final rows get a count of 1.  The outer query selects these and does the appropriate aggregation.

Comment: As i am getting the overall count of contract.. but the thing is i want to get the count like below.... 

Sample data here:
Contract_id      stat_new
---------------  ------------------------
CR 01 to MWO 1  Sent to xxxx Project Team
CR 01 to MWO 1  Sent to xxxx Project Team
CR 01 to MWO 1  Sent to xxxx Project Team
CR 01 to MWO 1  Sent to VMO

CR 01 to MWO 1  Sent to xxxx Project Team
CR 01 to MWO 1  Sent to xxxx Project Team
CR 01 to MWO 1  Sent to VMO

CR 01 to MWO 2  Sent to xxxx Project Team

Here, Same contract ID having 2 "Sent to VMO" values so i want the count of each set.

Comment: @Saravanan . . . This should be returning the values in the question.  Are you sure you have the `order by` clause on the `sum()`?